# SimpleI Injector - Register multiple database connections

Tags: c#, dapper, simple-injector, ormlite-servicestack

I'm working with an existing Web Api that uses Simple Injector to register a single database connection. I need to make an endpoint to get info from a different db but I don't know how to register a new connection.

These are the existing registrations for the main db:

```
_container.Register<IDataBaseSqlServerDapper>(
    () => new DataBaseSqlServerDapper(SqlServerDb.ConnectionString(),
    LogManager.GetLogger("")));

_container.RegisterWebApiRequest<IDbConnectionFactory>(
    () => new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(SqlServerDb.ConnectionString(),
    new SqlServerOrmLiteDialectProvider()));

_container.RegisterWebApiRequest(
    () => new PetaPoco.Database(Connection.SurveyEngine) {
        IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.Snapshot
    });
```

So I read about RegisterCollection method and I tried the following:

```
_container.RegisterCollection<IDataBaseSqlServerDapper>(new[]
{
   new DataBaseSqlServerDapper(SqlServerDb.ConnectionString(), LogManager.GetLogger("")),
   new DataBaseSqlServerDapper(AdmbbDb.ConnectionString(), LogManager.GetLogger(""))
});

_container.RegisterCollection<IDbConnectionFactory>(new[]
{
    new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(
        SqlServerDb.ConnectionString(), 
        new SqlServerOrmLiteDialectProvider()),
    new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(
        AdmbbDb.ConnectionString(), 
        new SqlServerOrmLiteDialectProvider())
});

_container.RegisterCollection<PetaPoco.Database>(new[]
{
     new PetaPoco.Database(Connection.SurveyEngine) { 
        IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.Snapshot },
     new PetaPoco.Database(Connection.Admbb) { 
        IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.Snapshot }
});
```

SqlServerDb, AdmbbDd and Connection are classes that contains the names of the connection strings.

But I'm getting this error:

> The configuration is invalid. Creating the instance for type IDapperQueryFactory failed. The constructor of type DapperQueryFactory contains the parameter with name 'dataBaseSqlServerDapper' and type IDataBaseSqlServerDapper that is not registered. Please ensure IDataBaseSqlServerDapper is registered, or change the constructor of DapperQueryFactory. There is, however, a registration for IEnumerable<IDataBaseSqlServerDapper>; Did you mean to depend on IEnumerable<IDataBaseSqlServerDapper>?

How can I solve this?

Comment: Your question is missing an important piece of information: how do you distinquish between these different databases? This is something you need to describe. Please describe who is _consuming_ these dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

In the existing case you specify that type `IDataBaseSqlServerDapper` can be used for injection, which in turn gets properly injected into your object (in this case a class that implements `IDapperQueryFactory`).

In the second case you are registering *multiple* services of type `IDataBaseSqlServerDapper`. Meaning that your DI does not know how to resolve a single `IDataBaseSqlServerDapper`, only a collection of them.

This means that you'll either have to change the constructor to accept `IEnumerable<IDataBaseSqlServerDapper>` or register a non-collection `IDataBaseSqlServerDapper`

Simple Injector's documentation lists a good example how you can use both `Register` and `Collection.Register` side by side to get it working ([source](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using.html#collections)).

---

Now as for your problem, you state:

> I need to make an endpoint to get info from a different db but I don't know how to register a new connection.

If you simply want to change where the data is going, can't you just replace the old existing handler?

If your goal is to load data from multiple datasources, you'll need to have some kind of logic that allows your code to determine which source it should use to store/load data.

*The example from the simple injector documentation provides a good basis for something like this that does not require you to rewrite classes that use an injected `IDataBaseSqlServerDapper`.*

Comment: I'm not changing where the data goes, I need to get info from another database within the same API.

Comment: Will it work if I register a non-collection and then I register a collection of the same type? I mean, the first connection as a single object and the other one as a collection item?

Comment: @AndreVillanueva according to their documentation it should. Check the [link](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using.html?highlight=RegisterCollection#collections), it shows an example with Loggers that does just that.

Answer (score 1):

My situation was similar to this, but a little bit simpler. I am posting my solution for anyone landing here with a problem like mine.

### The Problem

I needed a way to use multiple instances of a single concrete-type (in my case `NPoco.Database`) initialized with different parameters (connection string names). Since the [SimpleInjector doc examples](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using.html?highlight=RegisterCollection#collections) use classes that implement `ILogger` *and* all have parameter-less constructors, I was finding it difficult to figure out how to make my scenario work.

### The Solutuion

I finally came up with creating a simple sub-class of `NPoco.Database` for each database I needed to connect to, then using `Container.RegisterConditional` to register the instances. Since `RegisterConditional` does not have an overload that takes a constructor function, I had to give each of these sub-classes parameter-less constructors which called the base `Database` class with the proper connection string name. Lastly, some of the consumers were from an external NuGet package (internal to my organization) and relied on `IDatabase` being injected, not a derived type, so I could not just rely on registering derived types and letting SimpleInjector figure out based on that alone.

### The Code

With all that said, here is my solution.

#### Sub-Classes of NPoco.Database

```cs
public class FirstSubDatabase : Database
{
    public FirstSubDatabase()
        : base("FirstSubConnection") { }
}

public class SecondSubDatabase : Database
{
    public SecondSubDatabase()
        : base("SecondSubConnection") { }
}
```

#### Registration

```cs
container.RegisterConditional<IDatabase, FirstSubDatabase>(
    Lifestyle.Scoped,
    c => c.Consumer.ImplementationType.FullName?.StartsWith(
        "external.lib.", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ?? false);

container.RegisterConditional<IDatabase, SecondSubDatabase>(
    Lifestyle.Scoped,
    c => c.Consumer.ImplementationType == typeof(LocalConsumerClass));
```

Note: "external.lib." is just the namespace of everything from the external NuGet package. This saves future editors (including myself) of having to spend time figuring out why taking a dependency on another service from that package be instantiated.